# would complexity of constrained optimization problem bound the constraint satisfaction problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, constraint-satisfaction

For an optimization problem $x^* =\text{argmax}_xf(x)$ s.t. $x \in Y$ satisfy to some constraint $Y$.

Can I argue that if there is a polynomial algorithm for this optimization problem. Then there must exist a polynomial algorithm checking if $x$ satisfy constraint $Y$?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  What is the input, and what is the output?  It looks like there is no input, and thus there is always an algorithm for the optimization problem that runs in constant time (it hard-codes the solution to the optimization problem).